# MissingMethodException [Cannot create an instance of an interface] thrown selectively by ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

I'm getting strange (at least for me) behavior in an MVC 4 application.

I'm googling around this whole evening; also I read many SO posts - no joy; I know I can't instantiate an interface directly.

In this particular application I'm using Ninject for DI.
In the controller **constructor** I'm *instantiating an interface* and everything is peachy at that point - in fact I believe there is no problem with Ninject or its usage at all.

Also I'm sure this code was working once and no changes were introduced since then, except update of the Ninject library to 3.2.2.0 - can't remember which one was before that; obviously older one...

I have simple CRUD actions in that same controller which consumes another WEB service of mine. 2 out of 4 methods work correctly (LOL) - `Index()` and `Create()`. `Update()` and `Delete()` however are throwing the above mentioned exception; here it is the stack trace:

```
[MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an interface.]
    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean&amp; canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal&amp; ctor, Boolean&amp; bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
    System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark) +119
    System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark) +232
    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +183
    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +563
    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +416
    .
    .
    .
```

And here is the controller, very simple one, really...

```
public class NonFederalWorkingDayController : BaseController
{
    private readonly INonFederalWorkingDayManagementService _nonFederalWorkingDayService = null;

    public NonFederalWorkingDayController(INonFederalWorkingDayManagementService nonFederalWorkingDayService)
    {
        _nonFederalWorkingDayService = nonFederalWorkingDayService;
    }

    private JsonResultModel<IEnumerable<NonFederalWorkingDayDto>> InvokeService(Func<IEnumerable<NonFederalWorkingDayDto>, I9UserDto, IEnumerable<NonFederalWorkingDayDto>> operation, IEnumerable<NonFederalWorkingDayDto> models)
    {
        var result = new JsonResultModel<IEnumerable<NonFederalWorkingDayDto>>();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var modifier = new I9UserDto
            {
                Id = SiteContext.User.UserId
            };

            try
            {
                result.Model = operation(models, modifier);
                result.Message = "Operation completed successfully.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.HasError = true;
#if DEBUG
                result.Message = string.Concat("Operation failed: ", ex.Message);
#else
                result.Message = "Operation failed: Internal server error.";
#endif
            }

            if (result.Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var dto in result.Model)
                {
                    dto.CreatedOn = null;
                    dto.Creator = null;
                    dto.ModifiedOn = null;
                    dto.Modifier = null;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result.HasError = true;
            result.Message = "Invalid data.";
        }

        return result;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _nonFederalWorkingDayService.Load();

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<NonFederalWorkingDayDto> models)
    {
        var result = InvokeService(_nonFederalWorkingDayService.Create, models);

        return Json(result);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(IEnumerable<NonFederalWorkingDayDto> models)
    {
        var result = InvokeService(_nonFederalWorkingDayService.Update, models);

        return Json(result);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(IEnumerable<NonFederalWorkingDayDto> models)
    {
        var result = InvokeService(_nonFederalWorkingDayService.Delete, models);

        if (!result.HasError)
        {
            var plurality = models.Count() == 1 ? "Entity" : "Entities";
            result.Message = string.Concat(plurality, " deleted successfully.");
        }

        return Json(result);
    }
}
```

As I mentioned, the problem lies within the last two methods: `Update()` and `Delete()`. In fact, the execution never enters any one of them - the error gets raising during the model binding. But note how there is no interfaces except `IEnumerable<>` which binds just fine in other methods in the same application, including the `Create()` method in this very controller. I'm not sure how exactly, but the `DefaultBinder` seems smart enough to figure out that `IEnumerable` is actually a `List`. So this shouldn't be it, is it?

Also, I need to mention that I'm calling these actions through AJAX, not normal requests. Does that matters?

I seem to can't figure what is wrong ... please help!

**UPDATE**

I've inherit `DefaultModelBinder` in order to hook into the model binding pipeline. So I hooked into `BindModel()` and the `controllerContext.Controller` is actually fully functional instance of the `NonFederalWorkingDayController`

**UPDATE 2**

Here is the code listing for `NonFederalWorkingDayDto` :

```
public class NonFederalWorkingDayDto : DtoBase, INonFederalWorkingDay
{
    public static NonFederalWorkingDayDto Consume(INonFederalWorkingDay Donor)
    {
        NonFederalWorkingDayDto result = null;

        if (Donor != null)
        {
            result = DtoBase.Consume<NonFederalWorkingDayDto>(Donor);

            result.Description = Donor.Description;
            result.FallsOn = Donor.FallsOn;
            result.Id = Donor.Id;
            result.Name = Donor.Name;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime? FallsOn { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    #region INonFederalWorkingDay support

    DateTime INonFederalWorkingDay.FallsOn
    {
        get { return FallsOn ?? default(DateTime); }
    }

    int IIdentifier<int>.Id
    {
        get { return Id ?? default(int); }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: `var modifier = new I9UserDto` -- `I9UserDto` isn't an interface? It looks suspect with the error message.

Comment: It seems like an issue with controller instantiation using Ninject. Does your create works after updating ninject? and are there an interface inside NonFederalWorkingDayDto that might be initialized only in delete and update and not create? just a thought

Comment: @TyCobb Nope. The name might mislead you; `I9UserDto` is a class.

Comment: @XtremeBytes Yes. I can successfully create new objects by invoking `Create()` right now. In the same time, the `Update()` throws as well as `Delete()`. Strange, uh?

Comment: whats the structure for NonFederalWorkingDayDto?

Answer (score 0):

I think your action declarations are the issue, try:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(List<NonFederalWorkingDayDto> models)
{
    ...
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(List<NonFederalWorkingDayDto> models)
{
    ...
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(List<NonFederalWorkingDayDto> models)
{
    ...
}
```

Really the explanation is in the message i.e. it can't create an instance of the interface, as you've said the constructor is cool, so the problem lies with IEnumerable which needs to be a concrete enumerable class (like List for example).

Comment: Thank you, Paul, for your answer. Unfortunatelly it didn't help. The `DefaultModelBinder` recognizes the `IEnumerable<T>` and falls back to `List<T>`. Moreover, the `Create(IEnumerable<NonFederalWorkingDayDto> models)` currently works like a charm... if I put a breakpoint inside this method, the `models` parameter is an instance of `List'1`

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry, if I'd read your question again properly I would've seen that. Have you tried changing `var result = new JsonResultModel<IEnumerable<NonFederalWorkingDayDto>>();` to `var result = new JsonResultModel<List<NonFederalWorkingDayDto>>();` ?

Comment: I just did it, since you're suggesting so; no change. The `Update()` method is never entered actually; so is `InvokeService()` ... so changing the type of a variable inside non-executing method made no difference :(

Comment: hmmmm interesting, what's in `DtoBase`? Does it have a constructor with an interface?

Comment: Thank you Paul for you effort to figure this out. It turns out that the error is related to a DTO's children; it has nothing to do with the ASP.NET MVC or anything else; entirely my bad. It was a simple bug, but the error is thrown at such place, so it is misleading ...

Comment: No worries mate, glad you sorted it!